# Fatal error: run out of xids (xorg)

Tags: xorg

I've just installed slock (https://tools.suckless.org/slock/) a simple screen locker and whenever I call "slock", picom stops working. I start picom, my compositor, in the background through my .xprofile
Sometimes I also get an error message when calling "slock":

[ 10/24/2021 02:30:01.707 x_new_id FATAL ERROR ] We seems to have run of XIDs. This is either a bug in the X server, or a resource leakage in the compositor. Please open an issue about this problem. The compositor will die.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue that generally arises with picom's old backends on large screens.

Try to run picom with the **new backends** by passing the following flag:

> --experimental-backends

see: [Crash when slock is started](https://github.com/yshui/picom/issues/514) and [Picom crashes when running maim -s with an rotated display](https://github.com/yshui/picom/issues/482)